# Create TextViews and ImageViews while parsing Web Page

Tags: android, layout

The question is rather difficult to explain. 
I'm parsing a web page with JSoup, the page is a blog post. It changes sometimes. 
For example:

```
Look at my new car! 
*image here*
How do you Like it?
```

or

```
Yesterday I was doing nothing but watching TV
Such a rainy day.
```

All I want is to dynamically create TextView with text **before** image, then ImageView with image and TextView with text **after** image (or something more complicated) 
I tried this

```
this.setContentView(R.layout.post_test);

final ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.layout.post_test);

iv = new ImageView(this);
RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
rl.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
iv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
rl.addView(iv);
vg.addView(View.inflate(this, rl, null));
```

but with no luck.
I don't want to use WebView because of its bad appearance and not working with KitKat.
That's what I mean:
[image: Pic1]
[image: Pic2]